# Trouble installing Brackets.io

Tags: debian, software-installation

I am running normal Ubuntu Debian.

I've downloaded the Debian package from the official website: `Brackets.Release.1.14.1.64-bit.deb`.

When I right click "Install software" and try to 'Install' it, it goes to 100% and then returns to the same 'Install' icon, as if it never installed.

When I try installing on terminal via `sudo dpkg -i Brackets.Release.1.14.1.64-bit.deb`, it says I am missing some dependencies.

So I ran `sudo apt -f install` but it still doesn't install... and it says it's freeing up like 300 MB space... It's not working for me either way.

I exit terminal and try doing the same commands and I get the same results.

Can anyone please help me? I really need to use this code editor for a new Javascript course I started and I've already spent 3 hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: Update the repositories before trying to download again. If you're using a GUI there should be an option for that

Comment: What is the output of `sudo apt install ./Brackets.Release.1.14.1.64-bit.deb`?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to follow two different/independent methods with no errors. The steps are described in the page (https://itsfoss.com/install-brackets-ubuntu/). I tested the steps in a Ubuntu 18.04.5 Virtual Machine. See if you can do one of these methods. Disclaimer: I don't know to pros/cons of choosing either method, and if the specific version of the Brackets application for either method will end up to suit your need.

### Method 1:

```
user@testvm:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/brackets

user@testvm:~$ sudo apt-get update

user@testvm:~$ sudo apt-get install brackets

user@testvm:~$ which brackets
/usr/bin/brackets
```

### Method 2:

```
user@testvm:~$ sudo snap install brackets
error: This revision of snap "brackets" was published using classic confinement and thus may
       perform arbitrary system changes outside of the security sandbox that snaps are usually
       confined to, which may put your system at risk.

       If you understand and want to proceed repeat the command including --classic.

user@testvm:~$ sudo snap install --classic brackets
2020-09-23T22:01:43Z INFO Waiting for automatic snapd restart...
brackets 1.14.1 from Snapcrafters installed
```